# Use Order on Aggregate(in a single statement)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as below:

```
  A B
1 1 2
2 1 3
3 2 3
4 3 5
5 3 6
```

And I am applying `Aggregate` to get my data as below

```
> aggregate(B ~ A, mydf, sum)
  A  B
1 1  5
2 2  3
3 3 11
```

Now, I want to `order` my result based on `B`, so I applied the `Order` function as:

```
> aggregate(B ~ A, mydf[order(B),], sum)
```

which didn't work. And then I applied

```
> aggregate(B ~ A, mydf, sum)[order(B),]
```

which didn't work either

How should I use `Order` to get desired result.

Comment: `aggregate` uses NSE notation within its formula representation, while `[.data.frame` isn't. If you want to reorder by size of `B` you need to tell R what is `B` and where did you take it from, for example `res <- aggregate(B ~ A, mydf, sum) ; res[order(res$B), ]`. Alternatively, Using `data.table` devel version (>= 1.9.5 on GH) you can do this by reference, for example `library(data.table) ; res <- setorder(aggregate(B ~ A, mydf, sum), B)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg you have explained it beautifully. Why don't you put it as a answer. I'll be more than happy to accept it

Comment: Ok, Added an answer with some alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in comments, you can't just call `B` unless you tell R what is `B` exactly and when to get it from. Some people are using `attach` (**don't do this**) in order to make their life easier and call columns without being bothered using `$`, though in your case it will also fail because you are creating a temporary data set, while the attached `B` will come from the unaggregated data set.

```
attach(mydf)
aggregate(B ~ A, mydf, sum)[order(B),]
#       A  B
# 1     1  5
# 2     2  3
# 3     3 11
# NA   NA NA
# NA.1 NA NA
detach(mydf)
```

---

So now that we quit fooling around, with base R you can do as I mentioned in my comment and as was posted later in the above answer.

```
res <- aggregate(B ~ A, mydf, sum)  
res[order(res$B), ]
```

But this *won't* be in one statement and I'm not aware of a way of doing it otherwise.

Though, fortunately we have some packages that can achieve this in one call.

First, the `data.table` package ([in its devel version on GH](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)) can achieve this both easily and efficiently using the `setorder` function within the same call

```
# library(devtools)
# install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)
library(data.table) ## v >= 1.9.5
res <- setorder(aggregate(B ~ A, mydf, sum), B)
```

Though, if we already at it, the correct `data.table` syntax will be

```
res <- setorder(setDT(mydf)[, .(B = sum(B)), by = A], B)
```

---

An alternative approach will be using piping combined with the `dplyr` package in order to achieve the same goal in one chain of actions

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(B = sum(B)) %>%
  arrange(B)
```

Comment: the answer couldn't have been better. +1.

Comment: @Saksham, just please remember, `attach` was introduced as an example of bad coding. Please **never** use it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
myagg <- aggregate(B~A,mydf,sum)
myagg[order(myagg$B),]
```

Comment: was trying it to do without using an intermediate variable. but anyways thanks!

Answer (score -1):

@Saksham: If you insist upon one line code:

```
aggregate(B~A,mydf,sum)[order(aggregate(B~A,mydf,sum)),]
```